# Firebase get 2 subcollections count caching

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In a component in react, I wasnt to display the sum count of two subcollections in a specific document in a collection.

The issue is, each time I go to a different page and go back, the responses seem to refetch and take some time to display (even though the underlying data didn't change).

Here's how I'm implementing the count:

```
 const [count, setCount] = useState(null);

  const getItemsCount = async () => {
    const shelvesCollection = collection(db, "shelves");
    const shelfItemsCollection = collection(shelvesCollection, id, "items");
    const sliderItemsCollection = collection(shelvesCollection, id, "sliders");

    const [shelfSnapshot, sliderSnapshot] = await Promise.all([
      getCountFromServer(shelfItemsCollection),
      getCountFromServer(sliderItemsCollection),
    ]);

    const shelfCount = shelfSnapshot.data().count;
    const sliderCount = sliderSnapshot.data().count;
    const totalCount = shelfCount + sliderCount;

    setCount(totalCount);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getItemsCount();
  }, []);
```

Does this implementation make sense? Or is there a better way? Also, how to enable caching in firebase so that there's no lag (loading) when rendering the same component again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client-side SDKs for Firestore currently don't cache the count, which is why they're explicitly called `getCountFromServer`.

If you want to avoid the reload delay/cost, consider storing the count in local storage yourself.

You can then either:

- Display the count from the cache right away, and then load it from the server and refresh (if needed). This would mimic the behavior of an `onSnapshot` type listener for regular data.
- Determine how old the cached count is and call `getCountFromServer` in case the value is older than you think is reasonable.

Comment: Thank you Frank for the clarification! Another option I considered was to just call `.length `on the resulting array from a snapshot. Although that would of course load all the data which I may not want. That's why I decided to use the `getCountFromServer`